# jquery number validation not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validations in a form.  I haven't had many issues, however I did run into a problem in a users form where the jquery number validation isn't firing.  I tested it in IE, firefox and chrome and it is not working in any of them.  The weird part is that so far it seems that it is specific to this one user's form as when I go to other user forms the alerts fire fine as it does in my testing across all browsers.  I was wondering if any one else has come across this problem before when using jquery validation. Below is an example of some of the jquery validation code I am using.

```
    var validator = $("#educationForm").validate({
            debug: true,
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "help-block errortext",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                element.before(error);
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.remove();
            },
            rules: {
                school1GPA: {
                    number: true
                },
                school2GPA: {
                    number: true
                },
                school1Units: {
                    number: true
                },
                school2Units: {
                    number: true
                },
            },
            onsubmit: false
        });

    $('.form-actions').on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            if ($("#educationForm").valid()) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",............
        } else {
           validator.focusInvalid();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide also the `html` of this particular form?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are triggering `evt.preventDefault()` before you could even trigger `jquery` validation. That is basically killing any validation statement following `evt.preventDefault()`. All you need to is just call `$("#educationForm").valid()` or `jquery.validate()` and then call `evt.preventDefault()`.

```
 $('.form-actions').on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (evt) {

            if ($("#educationForm").valid()) {
                evt.preventDefault(); // prevents the form submission to allow ajax
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",............
        } else {
           validator.focusInvalid();
        }
});
```

Comment: Click handler is not needed and ajax belongs inside of plugin's `submitHandler` option.

Comment: Yes, you may do that too. Call specific validate related handlers.

Answer (score 0):

- You should not need your `click` handler at all.  [As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), your ajax belongs inside of the `submitHandler` callback function.
- You also should not set `onsubmit` to `false` unless you want validation blocked when the submit button is clicked.
- `debug` set to `true` will block submission of the form.

Something more like this...

```
 var validator = $("#educationForm").validate({
        // debug: true, // <- this is blocking the submit entirely
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax here
            $.ajax(...);
            return false;
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "help-block errortext",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.before(error);
        },
        success: function (label) {
            label.remove();
        },
        rules: {
            school1GPA: {
                number: true
            },
            school2GPA: {
                number: true
            },
            school1Units: {
                number: true
            },
            school2Units: {
                number: true
            },
        },
        // onsubmit: false  // <- this is preventing validation on the submit.
    });
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2vv8vL79/**